# Do we still know more about the Moon than Antarctica?

Tags: the-moon

I have no specific sources to cite, but years ago it seemed we had more general knowledge & study of the Moon than of Antarctica...
...Now however Antarctica is more studied than the Moon, & relevant to general space exploration...

Comment: This isn't really about the subject of space exploration, but we DO have a [skeptics site](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com) which is about challenging notable claims you encounter. Check it out and see if it is appropriate there. Perhaps it has already been asked and answered.

Comment: It's also quite an apples-and-oranges comparison. How do you quantify *knowledge* about two completely different research subjects?

Comment: I'll try to check the skeptics site to see if i misunderstood the order in which we learned about Antarctica & The Moon. But we now know far more about Antarctica & it's absolutely relevant to space exploration: Discovery of life, drilling, terraforming, etc etc.

Answer (score 11):

This is unlikely. After World War 2, dozens of countries opened research stations on Antarctica. There are [more than 50 stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_stations_in_Antarctica) at the moment, many of them operate year-round. Hundreds of scientists get the opportunity to visit and study Antarctica each year.
This is in sharp contrast with 6 manned Moon missions totaling a few weeks of human presence on the Moon, plus some unmanned probes.